# Twig if else syntax

Tags: twig

How  can I print not found when my hotel is empty using tiwg syntax

```
{% if hotels is empty %}
    <p>not found</p>
{% else %}
    {% for hotel in hotels %}                
        {% if  %}

        {% else %}

        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
{% endif %}
```

if my hotels is empty it didnt not found

Comment: Just use `{% for hotel in hotels %}...{% else %}No hotels found{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [twig doc of for loop](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html) mentions it very clearly.

Try this

```
{% for hotel in hotels %}                
    {% if  %}

    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>not found</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Thanks DarkBee for correcting me.